# child_process exec returning a mysterious error

Tags: node.js

I have the following code (copied from [the node docs](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) apart from the command itself) :

```
var util = require('util'),
    exec = require('child_process').exec,
    child,
    command = 'libreoffice --headless -convert-to pdf mysourcefile.doc -outdir /tmp';
child = exec(command,
           function (error, stdout, stderr) {
              if (error !== null) {
                 console.log(error);
                 return;
              }
           );
```

The command appears to be executing fine (output file is there) but error is always "Error: Command failed:" and err is not defined (the docs say err.code will give more information).

What am I doing wrong / overlooking?

Comment: I think you want `error.code`.

Comment: funny two years later and it seems that i just posted the same error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132657/nodejs-child-process-exec-java-version

Answer (score 1):

It should be `error.code`.

The docs mix the use of `error` and `err`; it refers to the `Error` object provided to the callback.

Comment: from nodejs docs "On success, error will be null. On error, error will be an instance of Error and err.code will be the exit code of the child process, and err.signal will be set to the signal that terminated the process."

Answer (score 1):

like i say . years after. i got the same error. just find what can be the error - checkout (https://stackoverflow.com/a/21137820/1211174). if you are on windows there is a chance that you have someauto run on cmd. and then this autorun failed. and you get both output. sterr and stdout