# ERROR: executing command 'ant' - After installation and setting ANT_HOME

Tags: node.js, cordova, ant

After wrestling with my environment variables to get the proper directory set, I can now get the version with:

```
C:\Projects\TestProj>ant -version
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
```

Ant appears to be working:

```
C:\Projects\TestProj>ant
Buildfile: build.xml does not exist!
Build failed
```

I still get the error when I try:

```
C:\Projects\TestProj>cordova -d platform add android
cordova library for "android" already exists. No need to download. Continuing.
Checking if platform "android" passes minimum requirements...
Creating android project...
Running command: C:\Users\Administrator\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\c
reate.bat --cli C:\Projects\TestProj\platforms\android com.company.testproj
TestProj

C:\Users\Administrator\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\node_modules\q\q.j
s:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error: ERROR : executing command 'ant', make sure you have ant installed and add
ed to your path.
```

From all of the posts that I have read, this is an issue with ANT_HOME, but it appears I have that part of it tackled.  *Edit* I've installed ant 1.9.3 to program files, and bin resides in: 
*EDIT* Changed to just ant, instead of apache-ant-1.9.3-bin\apache-ant-1.9.3

```
C:\Program Files\ant
```

Echo home:

```
C:\Projects\TestProj>echo %ANT_HOME%
C:\Program Files\ant
```

And of course I have %ANT_HOME%\bin in my path.  Any help identifying the issue would be appreciated.

Comment: Funny thing is that ANT_HOME is not defined in my computer and not called in check_reqs.js, so I don't think it's the problem.

Comment: check_reqs.js just runs `ant -version` and displays the message you see in case of error. I have no idea why node detects an error as ant seems to work when you run it manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path you use for ANT_HOME is wrong. `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ant\ant` seems to be the path to the [ant npm module](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ant) but not the ant command.

Ant command more probably is somewhere in program files. In a cmd, run `where ant` to know where in your path ant is found and use this path for ANT_HOME. (in the folder you should see ant, ant.cmd and ant.bat)

After further investigation, I think your problem is caused half by cordova not correctly checking node errors and half because of registry setting in your computer (a cmd autorun parameter).

You can check answers in those posts for more info:

- [nodejs child_process exec 'java -version'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132657/nodejs-child-process-exec-java-version/21137820#21137820)
- [Windows CMD.exe "The system cannot find the path specified."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13316682/windows-cmd-exe-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specified/13343337#13343337)

Check if you have a registry key `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun`

Comment: I've installed ant 1.9.3 and placed it in program files.  ant.cmd and and.bat are in the bin located at ANT_HOME.  where ant gives me an error about 'where' not being recognized.  Still have the same error.

Comment: Have you put it in `C:\Program Files` or in `C:\Program Files (x86)` ?  Cordova scripts seem to fail when and is located in folders with round brackets ().

Comment: I put it in C:\Program Files.  So my bin path is C:\Program Files\ant\bin, and my ANT_HOME is C:\Program Files\ant.  I just saw your edit about registry, will take a look.

Comment: Well, out of ideas sorry... When you add android platform, check_reqs.bat is launched ant it runs C:\Users\Nicolas\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.4.0\bin\lib\check_reqs.js which uses node.js's  child_process.exec function to run `ant -version` and detect errors. For some reason, in your case it detects errors. You can try to disable the test but it's likely it will fail somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for all the help!  I'll post any updates as I find them.  I don't actually need to build this because I'm just writing unit tests for the devs and used ripple to emulate.  They just had me go through the process.

Answer (score 0):

after setting the variables, restart your machine. Closing command prompt etc will not help.
Even I was stuck for quite a long time and next day when I started my system, it was working fine :P

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to get back to this issue.  However, I had tried rebooting after setting the variables and ended up with the same issue.  Real stumper.  Thanks for the response!